# React useState is undefined working with webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, react-hooks

I am building a simple react app with React hooks and webpack-dev-server. I would like to enable hot reload.

Running the `webpack-dev-server --mode development`, I got an error: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` and It complains at the folloing line which is compiled.

```
var _useState = Object(react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["useState"])(0),
```

This is my code
`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.jsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
    mainFiles: ['index']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

`Body.jsx`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Body = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`You clicked ${count} times`}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader/root';
import { setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader';

import Body from './Body';

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Body />
  </div>
);

export default hot(App);
```

`index.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

For dependencies, I am using react and react-dom with version 16.7.0-alpha.2.
react-hot-loader is version 4.6.3

Answer (score 1):

Sadly react-hot-loader is not compatible with hooks, atleast to my knowledge and their issue github page.
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088